# Local (sub) NetWorking between : VirtualBox with Deice on Win7 and local machine on Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox

I am staring a pen-testing lab.
But I encountered a problem whilst trying to access the vulnerable network from an other computer on my local network (i.e not the one running VirtualBox).

### The Setup :

The lab consist of 1 computer running  `win7` local IP is `192.168.0.30`

on which,
VirtualBox is running the following distribution :
 `De-ICE Live CD Level 1`
 
(the local networking of the distro is on the `192.168.1.x` range and is not editable)

The `De-ICE Live CD Level 1` is exposing a vulnerable website on `192.168.1.100` *(port 80)*

**networking is as follow** :
*(all netmasks are 255.255.255.0)*

on the VirtualBox  :

- VirtualBox Host-Only adapter set to **`192.168.1.1`**  With a DHCP
  Server `192.168.1.254`

on the Win7 machine :

- Ethernet Adapter that access the internet 192.168.0.30 (and is sharing connection with the VirtualBox Host-Only adapter)
- the VirtualBox Host-Only adapter is on static IP set to **`192.168.1.1`**,
  server DHCP Server `192.168.1.254`

---

### Now the question :

On the Windows 7 Machine I can access from a browser the vulnerable website on the subnet 192.168.1.100.

My pentesting tools are on a laptop running ubuntu accessing the local network on 192.168.0.23 via wifi connection.

***How can I access the 192.168.1.100 website from that computer aforementioned ?***

I have tried NetSH on the Win7 machine and port forwarding on my router but it only allows forwarding on local network **`192.168.0.x`** not subnet **`192.168.1.x`**

As I see it,
 I have to find a way to forward traffic arriving to my Win7 machine to the local subnet.

Is there a way in WIN7 to do just that :

> forward 192.168.0.30:[xyz] to 192.168.1.100:80 ?

Or is there a better way to access a subnet from a local network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way that works well.

1# I changed my network (192.168.0.x) to match the Virtual Machine network (192.168.1.x)

2# I unshared the connection between my Ethernet adapter and the virtual adapter

3# I bridged both adapters

4# I changed the VirtualBox connection adapter to Bridged, and choose the newly created bridged connection in the list.

5# launched the VM

I, now can access the 192.168.1.100 from my local computer as from any computer on my network.

When I run a Netdiscover on my Linux machine I see the VM as a local computer.

Answer (score 1):

<s>A quick and dirty solution would be to change your subnet from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.0.0, however, it sounds like that's not going to work on the live CD.</s>

A better solution would be to install a virtual router like pfSense, and route the traffic between the two subnets.

Another option is to use an SSH tunnel via Putty on the Windows machine. This most closely resembles what you were asking for.

http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html

### Update 1

Local and remote forward is explained very well here: http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html

The idea is to create a forward from `windows-ip:80` to `localhost:9000` and a second one from `localhost:9000` to `livecd-ip:80`. Port 9000 is arbitrary and can be any unused port on the machine.

This effectively redirects incoming traffic on port 80 to the live CD on port 80. If you already have a process using port 80 on the Windows machine, you can change it to `windows-ip:1234` or any other unused port, then point you pen test to that port instead. Traffic will still arrive at the live CD on port 80.

Comment: thx I'll have a try to this putty solution.

Comment: I've added some details to get you started with the port forwarding option.

Comment: thx for your help, I have found a way that works well. I haven't succeeded with Putty :/ The last option I had was to try run everything on the same network. Also I wasn't sur that the bridged connection would work in VirtualBox but it did. I have posted My solution if any one wants to experiment...

Comment: Glad you got it working. I didn't consider that you were willing to change your main subnet - that's certainly the best option in terms of simplicity. Also, I misunderstood the config and thought you were using a bridged connection when I read "sharing connection with the VirtualBox Host-Only adapter". My supernet suggestion would not have worked unless you were already using a bridged adapter, so I have removed it.